# Laravel: same functionality in different controllers?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement 2 functions that I need to use in 2 controllers, LoginController and RegisterController, these are functions I currently declare in 1 controller but I now need them in multiple controllers. I was just wondering what the best programming practice was?

What is the best way to do this, without breaking any coding rules?

Comment: What kind of functionality is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go is to define a new level of abstraction...

```
class MyLittleBronyController extends Controller
{
    public function defineItAsYouWant()
    {
        // whatever
    }
}

class YourControllerOne extends MyLittleBronyController
{
    // You'll have method defineItAsYouWant() available here.
}

class YourControllerTwo extends MyLittleBronyController
{
    // You'll have method defineItAsYouWant() available here.
}
```

Another is to define a trait, as Ruman noted, but it's less readable and I personally don't like it.

You could put your functionality into a service and inject it into your controller. You could do many other things. **A LOT** depends on your architecture. Your question is very broad and generally impossible to answer correctly without seeing your whole project. So go read Richard Martin and here's a pony for you, so that you don't ask silly broad questions here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can extract those 2 functions in a `trait` and use them in your Controllers.